# How to Make a looping image slide show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make a looping image slider?
Below is my code for an image slide show. I want to make the slide show loop i.e when last image appears and one clicks next button the first image should appear again. 
my JS is like this

```
function worksCarousel(){
var totalWorks = $(".wrapper-project ul li").length;
var ampleWork = $(".project-content").width();
var ampleTotalWorks = totalWorks*ampleWork;
$('.wrapper-project ul').css('width',ampleTotalWorks)

var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
li = document.createElement('li');
while (totalWorks--) {
    fragment.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));
}

$('.controller-3 ul').append(fragment);

var index3 = 0;
var pos3 = 1;
$('.controller-3 ul li:first-child').addClass('selected');

$(".controller-3 ul li").click(function(){
    index3 = $(this).index();
    $(".wrapper-project").stop().animate({scrollLeft:ampleWork*index3},'slow');
     $('.controller-3 ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    //alert(ampleitem);
});
$(".w-next").click(function(){
        if( index3 != $(".controller-3 ul li").size()-1){
          index3++;
          $(".wrapper-project").stop().animate({scrollLeft:ampleWork*index3},'slow');
          pos3++;
          $('.controller-3 ul li.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
    }
   });
$(".w-prev").click(function(){
  if( index3!=0 ){
      index3--;
      $(".wrapper-project").stop().animate({scrollLeft:ampleWork*index3},'slow');
      pos3--;
      $('.controller-3 ul li.selected').removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected');
  }
});
}
```

and my html code is

```
<div class="nav-work">
<div class="w-prev">Next</div>
<div class="w-next">Prev</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-project">
<ul>
    <li><img alt="" src="{tag_portfolio image 1_value}" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" src="{tag_portfolio image 2_value}" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" src="{tag_portfolio image 3_value}" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" src="{tag_portfolio image 4_value}" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" src="{tag_portfolio image 5_value}" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>


</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ffy7y7ck/. take a look at this fiddle. this is the way how I make my image sliders. I hope it will help you with your image slider. I used Jquery for this

Comment: thnaks for your quick reply. But i need to solve the problem by ammending the baove code. Can you help me in that

Comment: can you make a fiddle pls? than can I see what problem is

Comment: @IshfaqMuzaffar would be much easier to help you by having an example that includes CSS

Comment: @IshfaqMuzaffar also it's of no help if you add HTML that is not relevant for your *Gallery*. By posting unnecessary code you just make people wonder *wth is that here for*. Strip the code to the essentials  `.clear, #project-show, .w-arrows, .btn bla bla` are just noise.

Comment: i will try to create a fiddle do that you may know what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution that could give ideas would be as follows:

1. Store in an array the container of the images or the images you want to show.
2. Keep the index of the current image shown in a variable.
3. Update the value of the index and the image shown whenever the user clicks prev or next.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffy7y7ck/3/)

```
var images_li = $(".wrapper-project ul li").toArray(), current_img = 0;
$(images_li[current_img]).show();

$(".btn-prev").click(function(){
    $(images_li[current_img]).hide();
    current_img = (current_img === 0) ? images_li.length - 1 : current_img - 1;
    $(images_li[current_img]).show();
});

$(".btn-next").click(function(){
    $(images_li[current_img]).hide();
    current_img = (current_img === images_li.length-1) ? 0 : current_img + 1;
    $(images_li[current_img]).show();
});
```